# Determining where a function is defined in C#?

Tags: c#, methods

I am a complete novice at C# (I've never used it before) and recently needed to look over some code written in it.  I spent the longest time trying to track down a nonexistent method in a class that didn't seem to be defined anywhere in the class that was using it.  I later found out it was an "extension method," which I gather is a method grafted onto another class by some source.

I completely understand the rationale behind this language feature and actually think it's quite nice.  However, as someone without much experience in the language, it makes it harder to look up unfamiliar methods, since the method in question could be defined anywhere.

My question is this: given an unfamiliar method call in C#, what's the best way for me to look up more info on it, given that it could be an extension method defined in an entirely separate class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply right-click the function and select "Goto definition".

Comment: @Joey Na! I thought that, too, but I recently stood at a co-workers PC and told him to hit `F12` which he did and nothing happened. I think he accidentially selected a different default keyboard layout. So `F12` helps most of the time, but sometimes not... :-)

Comment: @Uwe Keim, I have never, ever seen a keyboard layout with different functions keys. Maybe he set it on the Ewok language?

Comment: That works, but I'm currently in Linux using emacs. :-). Thanks though!

Comment: @Dykam I'll ask him on monday. IIRC on the very first start of VS.NET after the initial installation you can select which environment you like, something like "C# Developer", "Web Development", etc. This pretty much configures the keyboard and screen layout.

Comment: Oh, that keyboard layout. I thought you meant it as in `qwerty`,`dvorak`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

On the standard C# environment key set:

`F12` : Go to definition

`Cntrl + -(Minus)` : Go back to the last mouse position (basically go back to where you were before)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of information do you want? If it regular extension that are defined in the framework you can search information on [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US). Except for that I also recommend the solution that Uwe Keim wrote, right click and select "Goto definition".